# Rotate an image around x or y axis in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

If a camera is looking at say 6 evenly spaced dots in the real world it would look like the image below if the camera is looking at the image straight on with no rotation in the x, y or z axis

[image]

The z-axis is perpendicular to the image sensor so rotation around the z-axis is simple, it's just a tilt of the image. If I were to rotate the camera (or objects being looked at) around the x axis (if the x-axis is up down) the rows and columns will no longer be parallel and would project off to a vanishing point, like this.

[image]

What I would like to do is take a 2 dimensional image of say, dots, and be able to apply different rotations around the x,y and z axes independently. I've experimented with reading my image in Matlab and multiplying by a rotation matrix, or even a full camera matrix but I can't figure out how to take a 2D image, simulate rotating it around the x axis and then saving that back to an image.  So that my original grid of dots would look like the bottom image with lines going off to a vanishing point. I've seen some examples using imwarp but I didn't see how I can set the angle of rotation. I'm working on camera calibration so I really want to be able to specify an angle of rotation around each axis.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: The angles of rotation are specified in the [`tform`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imwarp.html#btqog63-1-tform) object.

Comment: @beaker, yes they are but I want to do a 3D rotation on a 2D image. Does the image need to be converted to 3D first? This is what I"m stuck on.